# awk one row substracts the next row if their first two colums are the same

Tags: awk

If we would like to substract $17 if their $1 & $2 are the same:  input

```
targetID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
 111,CPD-123456,2222,1111,IC50,,6.1,uM,1183,1265,Ki,,0.16,uM,,38.125,1.7511,2003-03-03 00:00:00,2003-02-10 00:00:00,Cell,Enzyme
 111,CPD-123456,2222,1111,IC50,,9.02053,uM,1183,1265,Ki,,0.16,uM,,56.3783,-1.5812,2003-02-27 00:00:00,2003-02-10 00:00:00,Cell,Enzyme
 111,CPD-777888,3333,4444,IC50,,6.1,uM,1183,1265,Ki,,0.16,uM,,38.125,-1,2003-03-03 00:00:00,2003-02-10 00:00:00,Cell,Enzyme
 111,CPD-777888,3333,4444,IC50,,9.02053,uM,1183,1265,Ki,,0.16,uM,,56.3783,-3,2003-02-27 00:00:00,2003-02-10 00:00:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

The desired output should be (1.7511-(-1.5812)=3.3323); (-1-(-3)=2)

```
3.3323
2
```

First attempt:

```
awk -F, ' last != $1""$2 && last{     # ONLY When last key  "TargetID + Cpd_number"
      print C                 # differs from actual , print line + substraction
      C=0}                    # reset acumulators
  { # This block process each line of infile
      C -= $17                # C calc
   line=$0                    # Line will be actual line without activity
   last=$1""$2}               # Store the key in orther to track switching
   END{ # This block triggers after the complete file read
       # to print the last average that cannot be trigger during
       # the previous block
      print C}' input
```

It will give the output:

```
-0.1699
 4
```

The second attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -n+2 test > test2   # remove the title/header

awk -F, '$1 == $1 && $2 == $2 {print $17}' test2 >> test3  # print $17 if the $1 and $2 are the same

awk 'NR==1{s=$1;next}{s-=$1}END{print s}' test3

rm test2 test3
```

test3 will be

```
 1.7511
-1.5812
-1
-3
```

Output is

```
7.3323
```

Could any guru kindly give some comments?  Thanks!

Comment: please remove the `**` from your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below awk command,

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1{next} {var=$1; foo=$2; bar=$17; getline;} $1==var && $2==foo{xxx=bar-$17; print xxx}' file
3.3323
2
```

Comment: It could be simplified to "awk -F, 'NR==1{next} {bar=$17;getline;} $1==$1 && $2==$2{xxx=bar-$17; print xxx}'"

Comment: I think i was missing "getline" when I wrote this script.  After reading the manual of "getline", I still don't quite understand the "getline" meaning here.  Could you kindly explain it?  Thanks!  https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html

Comment: @Chubaka getline function is used to fetch the next line. After assigning the col1 and col2 values of first line to var, foo variable, and $17 to bar variable, Next line is fetched now the next line was assigned to $0 and the nextline column1 was assigned to $1 like that. I think now you understand.

Comment: I see.  So "getline" has the function of reading the next line while "next" just jump to the next line and ignore the current line, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
  BEGIN { FS = "," }

  NR == 1 { next }          # skip header line

  {                         # accumulate totals
    if ($1 SUBSEP $2 in a)    # if key already exists
      a[$1,$2] -= $17           # subtract $17 from value
    else                      # if first appearance of this key
      a[$1,$2] = $17            # set value to $17
  }

  END {                     # print results
    for (x in a)
      print a[x]
  }
' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment.  However, the output will become "2
3.3323" instead of "3.3323 2".